# Create a two column list excluding 0 values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This seems extremely easy, but I just can't seem to get my head around it. So I have two columns. A has names and B has values. All I want to do is duplicate this list (into column D and E) just excluding 0 values in column B.(I put an example of what I am looking for below)

[image]

I am not that great at excel so this has been a bit of a challenge. I am trying to get it to work with a formula as I need it to automatically update when the values in column B change.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't an [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-filter-details-BBD0CB0A-8F90-43DF-BF77-6AD3774DC420) be appropriate for this?

Comment: You could filter the original range, and then use this for copying visible cells only
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-and-paste-visible-cells-only-6F655372-4EA0-4221-BF68-272422419B59

Comment: I tried that @Jeeped but the data doesn't automatically update you need to manually refresh the filter.

Comment: OK So this is not a one time task, you want the copied stuff to be updated.
Since I am more of a programmer and not a power user I ten dt to use VBA for this. Should be fairly easy to do that in VBA. Probably there are array formulas etc you could use to not having to resort to VBA

Comment: Yeah this is part of a report generator so the values in column will be updated frequently @dgorti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have a formula version that should work. Pull the first nonzero row over to D2:E2 (either manually or with simple index formulas) and then use the following in D3 and E3:

```
D3=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(D2&E2,$A$1:$A$99&$B$1:$B$99,0),0,99),MATCH(TRUE,(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(D2&E2,$A$1:$A$99&$B$1:$B$99,0),0,99)<>0),0)),"")

E3=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(D2&E2,$A$1:$A$99&$B$1:$B$99,0),0,99),MATCH(TRUE,(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(D2&E2,$A$1:$A$99&$B$1:$B$99,0),0,99)<>0),0)),"")
```

Then auto-fill to the bottom of your list.

Note that these are array formulas, so they must be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Also, if your list is longer than 99 then update all the 99's in the formula to a number at least as large as your list length.

The way this works is by using an `OFFSET` formula to start the search for non-zero values just below the previously listed result.

Comment: Thanks you so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pivot table. Drag Goals to the rows, Values to the values field well. Then right-click  any of the goals in the pivot table and select Filter > Value Filters, and filter on the value total to be not zero.

[image]

When more data is added to the sheet, just refresh the pivot table, which could be automated with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use if formulas to check the value like this...

```
'Column D formula:
=IF(E1="","",A1)

'Column E Formula:
=IF(B1=0,"",B1)
```

Although I doubt this is what you are looking for as it would just leave blank cells in column D and E if the value in column B is 0.

I would recommend using a macro that can be much more dynamic in nature.

```
    Sub Check_Values()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("D:E").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim name As Integer, val As Integer
Dim name1 As Integer, val1 As Integer
Dim Emptyrw As Long, Emptyrw1 As Long, Emptyrw2 As Long
Dim i As Integer

name = 1
val = 1
name1 = 1
val1 = 1
Emptyrw = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) + 1
Emptyrw1 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D:D")) + 1
Emptyrw2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("E:E")) + 1
i = 1

Do While val < Emptyrw
    If Cells(val, 2) <> 0 Then
    Range(Cells(name, 1), Cells(val, 2)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Cells(Emptyrw1, 4), Cells(Emptyrw2, 5)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    name = name + 1
    val = val + 1
    name1 = name1 + 1
    val1 = val1 + 1
    Emptyrw1 = Emptyrw1 + 1
    Emptyrw2 = Emptyrw2 + 1

Loop

Do While i < Emptyrw1
    If Cells(i, 4) = "" Then
    Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 5)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

You can just copy this code into your VBA and assign a command button to it and should work for you.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

My effort...

Enter into D2 using Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$20<>0,ROW($A$2:$A$20),999),ROWS(A$2:A2)),1)&""
```

Then fill down and across.

Make the "999" large enough to always be beyond the list of values.

Downside: appending the "" to prevent zeros showing up makes numbers behave as text.

[image]